# Create Temporal Table in Azure DB

Tags: azure-sql-database, temporal-tables

I am using SSMS 17 and are trying to create a temporal table in SQL Azure but for some reason the option Tables -> New -> Temporal Table is disabled.
I have created a basic Azure database which currently has no tables.
Does anybody know how to enable this feature or what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: why not use tsql

Answer (score 2):

The grayed out option in Object Explorer that you are seeing was an unintentional limitation in SSMS, which was probably true in the early days of Azure SQLDB.

The issue has been fixed quite some time ago, but it was never (and never will) be ported back to SSMS 17.x. Could you install the latest SSMS 18.x (currently SSMS 18.2) and give it a try?

If you are still having issues, please reach out to us on UserVoice (https://aka.ms/sqlfeedback).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, that option only appears if you connect to the SQL on Azure VM using "sa" account ( sql 2017 - 14.0.2072.2 ) , but not to Azure SQLDB ( 12.0.2000.8 ). So it could be a version issue although SQLDB supposedly is SQL 2016 plus, and this temporal table was there since 2016 )  Please try T-SQL as explained in the documentation `snippet` ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/creating-a-system-versioned-temporal-table?view=sql-server-2017#creating-a-temporal-table-with-a-user-defined-history-table )  that works.

Answer (score -1):

On SQL Server Management Studio, make a right click to Tables --> Select New --> Choose "System-Versioned Table".

Comment: That option doesn't appear to exist.I am usign the new version of sql management studio and the only options available are Table, Memory Optimized Table, Temporal Table (greyed out), Graph Table and External Table.

Comment: Newer versions of SSMS do not have this option anymore.

Answer (score -1):

You can use below screen shot also 
just right click on table and follow below screen shot
[image]